# Why typescript forces wrong variable name resolution

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, cypress

I recently created a [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) project to which I added [cypress](https://www.cypress.io). I added a support file called `setup.ts` (located at `repositoryRoot/cypress/support/setup.ts`) which has the following code:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    cy
});
```

I want to write `cy.wrap({setting1: 'value1'}).as('settings')` however when I type `cy.` typescript autocomplete **forces** the `cy.` to become `crypto.`. I tried disabling autocomplete by it doesn't help. Frankly, I don't understand whether this is caused by autocomplete of the IDE or typescript variable name resolution, as this happens both in VSCODE and codesandbox.

This is the link to the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-bash-o022q?file=/cypress/support/setup.ts:23-30), the issue is reproducible in the sandbox I'm wondering how to have the IDE to allow me to type `cy.wrap()` ideally with the autocomplete for methods available in cypress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I was able to solve the issue was to install the npm package `@types/cypress` (even though it's supposed to be included in newer versions of Cypress).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer:
Include this in the top of the spec file: `/// <reference types="Cypress" />`.

You might also need to reset your TS server with the command `cmd shift p` then search for Restart TypeScript server.

Also, your test file should be in the `integration` folder by default. Currently, it is not.

Comment: Following the steps you described didn't help (you can follow the steps in the sandbox link to check). Also why can't I use `beforeEach` in a support file? I want the aliases I create in the support file to be available in all integrations files.